# Bokeh: edit all options inside plot

Tags: python, bokeh, linechart

I've got a chart with multiple lines, like so:

```
p=figure()
p.line(x,y)
p.line(x1,y1)
p.line(x2,y2)
```

Is there a simple way for me to add options to all lines after the fact, instead of repeating them in each insertion?

E.g. `p.lines(line_width = 2, line_alpha=0.2)`

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a [theme](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/themes.html#bokeh.themes.Theme):

```py
from bokeh.io import curdoc, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.themes import Theme

p = figure()
p.line([1,2,3], [4,5,6], color="red")
p.line([1,2,3], [6,2,4], color="blue")

curdoc().theme = Theme(json={
    'attrs': {
        'Line': { 'line_width': 10, 'line_alpha': 0.2, },
    }
})

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to set the theme for the figure rather than the curdoc?

Comment: As of Bokeh 1.4 there is not. There is a proposal to broaden theming capability but it has not been implemented: https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/9339